# How to pass a view class with values to controller and adds to a list?

Tags: c#

Ok, so I am trying to pass values from DvdView.cs to DvdController.cs. I want to pass id, readTitle, readReleaseYear, readDirector, readRating from the GetNewDvdInfo() method in DvdView.cs to CreateDvd() in DvdController.cs. The problem is that according to the requirements, they expect that CreateDvd() to be private. My list of Dvds are being saved to DvdRepository.cs. Note, I have been told that controller should be the only one calling methods.

Update: I posted DvdRepository.cs, I commented out the method I was using. Should this method be removed?

**DvdView.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DvdManager.Models;

namespace DvdManager.View
{
    public class DvdView
    {
        public int GetMenuChoice()
        {
            string input;
            int choice;

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Press 1 to display movies");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 2 to add movie");
            input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (int.TryParse(input, out choice))
            {
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:                        
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        GetNewDvdInfo();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
                        break;
                }

            }
            return choice;


        }

        public Dvd GetNewDvdInfo()
        {
        string inputReleaseYear;
        string inputRating;

        int id = 4;
        string readTitle;            
        int readReleaseYear;
        string readDirector;            
        float readRating;

            Console.WriteLine("What is the Title of the DVD?");
            readTitle = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("What is the Release Year of the DVD?");
            inputReleaseYear = Console.ReadLine();
            int.TryParse(inputReleaseYear, out readReleaseYear);

            Console.WriteLine("Who is the Director of the DVD?");
            readDirector = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("What is the star rating of the DVD?");
            inputRating = Console.ReadLine();
            float.TryParse(inputRating, out readRating);

            return null;
        }
```

**DvdController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DvdManager.Models;
using DvdManager.Data;
using DvdManager.View;

/* 
    Run() : void
    Private CreateDvd(): void
    Private DisplayDvds(): void
    Private SearchDvds(): void
    Private EditDvd() : void
    Private RemoveDvd() : void
*/

namespace DvdManager.Controllers
{
    public class DvdController
    {
        public DVDList _dvds = new DVDList(); //From DvdRepository.cs

        public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome To Dvd Manager");

            CreateDvd();
        }

        private void CreateDvd()//Create
        {
            List<Dvd> Dvds = _dvds.GetList();

            Dvds.Add(new Dvd(0, "Batman", 2010, "Bruce", 4));
            Dvds.Add(new Dvd(1, "Superman", 2009, "John", 4));
            Dvds.Add(new Dvd(2, "Wonderwoman", 2012, "Omar", 4));
            DisplayDvds();
        }

        private void DisplayDvds() //Read List<Dvd> dvds
        {
            List<Dvd> Dvds = _dvds.GetList();

            for (int i = 0; i < Dvds.Count; i++)
            {                
                Console.WriteLine(Dvds[i]);
            }

            RemoveDvd();
        }
```

**DvdRepository.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DvdManager.Models;

/*
    Create(Dvd dvd) : Dvd
    ReadAll() : List<Dvd>
    ReadById() : Dvd
    Update(int id, Dvd dvd) : void
    Delete(int id) : void
*/

namespace DvdManager.Data
{
    public interface DvdRepository
    {


        Dvd Create(Dvd dvd);
        List<Dvd> ReadAll();
        //IEnumerable<Dvd> ReadAll();
        Dvd ReadById();
        void Update(int id, Dvd dvd);
        //Dvd Update(int id, Dvd dvd); //dvd item
        void Delete(int id);
        //Dvd Delete(int id);
    }

    /*public class DVDList
    {
        private List<Dvd> dvds = new List<Dvd>();

        public List<Dvd> GetList()
        {
            return dvds;
        }
    }*/
}
```

Comment: It does not make sense to have ALL those methods `private`. Well you could, and then have other `public` methods call on them, but that's really meaningless too. What's the reason for those to be private?

Comment: I have been told the view can not access the controller. Why? Its just something they want me to figure out on my own. This is to prepare me for web application, I believe.

Comment: The controller should be calling methods is the reason behind this. Sounds like what I am doing to get list from DvdRepository. I am using a public method to be able to get the list but the list itself remains private itself in the repository. I believe I have to do something similar to what I did here. I do believe you have to create a public method but don't know the best solution to this. Also NOTE: DVDList comes from DvdRepository.cs

Answer (score 0):

1. `DvdController` is not a view of MVC PATTERN its just a simple class.
2. To call your class from the controller:

```
var myView = new DvdView();
var dvdInfos = myView.GetNewDvdInfo();
```

For more info about ASP.NET MVC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass data that way!

Assuming MVC:

- The controller is called from the UI / consuming service.
- The Controller calls the Business logic / Repository layers
- That data can be the sent from the Business / Repo and sent to additional class and methods for manipulation

So, super pseudo code:

```
public class DvdController 
{
    public List<DVD> GetDvdsAuthors()
    {
        var dvds = DvdRepository.GetDvds();
        var authors = DvdRepository.GetAuthorsForDvds(Dvds);
        var DvdsWithAuthors = Views.GetDvdView(dvds, authors);
     }
}
```

Comment: When I type in DvdRepository, it does not see any methods after typing dot, I posted this class in the info, am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What you have posted is an Interface, not a class. You need a class that implements that interface. The interface should also be named IDvdRepository , and then the class would be defined like `public class DvdRepository : IDvdRepository`